# Is it possible to send messages from Kafka to Open Search?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, opensearch

i'm writing a service using Java, i'm learning so it is for study purpose.
I wrote my rest app and it's working fine, then i added kafka that's sending a message to a consumer every time i do a request through insomnia and it's working.
Now the problem is that i have to store the message from the consumer to Open Search running inside Docker, (only using Java, without Spring Boot ecc...) is there a way to do it? I can't find anything.

That's my Consumer:

```
String servers = "localhost:9092";
    String groupId = "id";
    String topic = "mytopic";

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, servers);
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

    KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
    kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic));

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class.getName());

    while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(3000));
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            logger.info("Key:" + record.key() + ", Value:" + record.value());
            logger.info("Partition:" + record.partition() + ", Offset:" + record.offset());
        }
    }
```

And that's my producer:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServer);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());

    KafkaProducer<String, String> kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);

    ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>("mytopic", null, message);
    kafkaProducer.send(record);
    kafkaProducer.flush();
    kafkaProducer.close();
```

EDIT: I forgot to tell that i already have Open Search up on Docker and already created an index, i have to insert the message i'm going mad..

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt

Comment: You're right mate but it's been like 2 days of search and i found nothing, except for this i build the project so a little bit of work it's done, however i appreciate your time, blessings!

Comment: So, searching "opensearch Kafka Connector" returns zero results? Or how about "write document to opensearch with Java"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists a Kafka Connector for OpenSearch. You do not need to write code for this (nor should you).

https://github.com/aiven/opensearch-connector-for-apache-kafka

Kafka Connect is a Java Framework...

Regarding Docker, see https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/extending.html

Otherwise, Opensearch has a REST API, so you'd write a Kafka Consumer process to write data to it rather than just printing to the console

Comment: In the Git repo it says to place "opensearch-connector-for-kafka" into "/kafka-connect-plugins", but how am i supposed to do if in my kafka folder ther aren't any references about "kafka-connect-plugins? Sorry but i'm newbie, thx 4 ur time!

Comment: You can create any folder name you want for `plugin.path` kafka connect config